# Does super always reach to NSobject class in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

the super keyword tells the compiler to search for method in the superclass of the class where the method is firstly defined. For example, if Class Father defines a new method called X which contains [super init], then I use method X in Class Son, the compiler would search for init method in Class Grandfather, since X is firstly defined in Class Father.

My question is, what if there exists a inherited method of NSObject that has not changed? For example, what if I use "init" method in a subclass that contains super? Since in this case, the init method is firstly defined in NSObject itself. Would it "skip over" NSObject, or just implements whatever inside NSObject since there is no higher classes?

```
-(id)init 
{         
   self=[super init];
  //code continues
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What `super` means is that Objective-C calls the method on the `self` object, but does not use the implementation of the method in the same class as the one where `super` was called. Slightly confusing, but consider this:

```
@interface Grandparent : NSObject
- (void)a;
- (void)b;
@end

@implementation Grandparent
- (void)a {NSLog(@"Grandparent a");}
- (void)b {NSLog(@"Grandparent b");}
@end

@interface Parent : Grandparent
@end

@implementation Parent
- (void)a {NSLog(@"Parent a"); [super a];}
@end

@interface Offspring : Parent
- (void)a {NSLog(@"Offspring a"); [super a];}
- (void)b {NSLog(@"Offspring b"); [super b];}
@end
```

Look at the implementation of `-[Offspring b]`. It calls `[super b]`, but `Parent` doesn't provide an implementation of `-b`. Objective-C will carry on looking up the hierarchy until it finds `-[Grandparent b]`, and executes that. If `Grandparent` didn't have the method it would look on `NSObject`.

Now consider calling `-[Offspring a]`. That logs a message, then calls `[super a]`, which is the implementation on `Parent`. That message in turn calls `[super a]`—because it does it in a method defined on `Parent`, this will start looking for `-[Grandparent a]` (even though the instance is actually an `Offspring` object).

What all this means is that for any `NSObject` descendent, calling a message via `super` has the possibility of ending up at the `NSObject` implementation of the method. That's not the same as saying that `super` *always* reaches `NSObject`, because there are classes in Objective-C that don't derive from `NSObject` (such as `NSProxy`).

Comment: I checked again in Xcode with some tweaks and it seems that "super" can bypass explicitly implemented methods. For example, if Parent defines and implements a new method "c" which does [super a], and if you do [offspring1 c] in main.m, the super would bypass "a" in Parent and checks "a" in Grandparent, even if Parent is the first superclass of Offspring.So I guess explicit implementation is the key of using "super"?

Comment: @Rexroth as I said, it starts at the superclass of the class where the method is defined. Your `c` method is defined on `Parent`, therefore `super` resolution will begin with `Grandparent`.

Comment: So if I define "c" again in Offspring, it would be considered as overriding, or "redefining", even if the codes are exactly the same? Because if I were to explicitly implement "c" in Offspring's @implementation, then it starts in class Parent, which is the superclass of the class where "c" is "redefined".

Comment: There are two things here: [i] you could find that out by testing it; [ii] yes, if you supply an implementation for a method, that counts as implementing the method :).

Answer (score 1):

You're right. Let's say neither Father nor Grandfather override `init`, but Son does, using the implementation in your snippet. If you do `[[aSon alloc] init]`, the call to `[super init]` would look for Grandfather's implementation of `init`, which wouldn't be found, and then it would get to NSObject's implementation, which would then be executed.

Comment: `super` does **not** look at actual object's class.